# Using Cayley/regular representation to prove $|g| \mid |G|$

Tags: group-theory

Cayley/regular representation says that the cycle lengths for each cycle for a permutation is the same. (e.g. $g = (1 2 3)(4 5 6)(7 8 9)$; lengths for each cycle are all 3.)

How do I show that this implies $|g| \mid |G|$ (the order of every element in the group divides the order of the group)?

What if we have a group with $5$ elements, and say $4$ of the elements $\in G$ have order $4$, and $1$ of the elements $\in G$ has order $1$? Clearly $4$ does not divide $5$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you accept the cycle decomposition, note that each element of $G$ appears in one of the cycles; since they cycles are of equal length, it follows the length of the cycle divides $|G|$. Now suppose $g$ has such a cycle representation. Since $g^{|g|} = e$, it follows that each cycle to the power of $|g|$ is trivial. But no smaller power $g^k$ of $g$ acts as $(1)$, for it would send $e \in G$ to $g^k \neq e$. That means the length of the cycles is $|g|$.

So you can't have a group of order 5 and elements of orders not dividing 5.

Comment: How do you know that every element in $G$ must appear in one of the cycles of a permutation?

Comment: Every element $x$ is mapped somewhere (to $gx$), so $(x\ gx\ g^2x\ \cdots)$ must appear in the cycle decomposition of the permutation induced on $G$ by left multiplication by $g$. The cycles can all be of length 1, if $g=e$; that's okay too. But every element appears in some cycle simply because it's a permutation.